# Android Source Compilation Error: Panic in minibp due to 'too many errors'

Tags: android, ubuntu, compilation, virtual-machine

I'm working on compiling the Android source code and encountered an error that causes the build process to fail. The error seems to be triggered during the execution of minibp. Here's the error log:

```
[1/1] out/soong/.minibootstrap/minibp out/soong/.bootstrap/build.ninja
FAILED: out/soong/.bootstrap/build.ninja 
out/soong/.minibootstrap/minibp -t -l out/.module_paths/Android.bp.list -b out/soong -n out -d out/soong/.bootstrap/build.ninja.d -o out/soong/.bootstrap/build.ninja Android.bp
panic: too many errors

goroutine 22 [running]:
github.com/google/blueprint/parser.(*parser).error(0xc420285b80, 0x6c0a80, 0xc420288c20)
    build/blueprint/parser/parser.go:134 +0x317
github.com/google/blueprint/parser.(*parser).errorf(0xc420285b80, 0x696e73, 0x15, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    build/blueprint/parser/parser.go:139 +0x75
github.com/google/blueprint/parser.newParser.func1(0xc420285b80, 0x696e73, 0x15)
    build/blueprint/parser/parser.go:115 +0x4f
text/scanner.(*Scanner).error(0xc420285b80, 0x696e73, 0x15)
    /home/chaos/android_build/prebuilts/go/linux-x86/src/text/scanner/scanner.go:327 +0x2d1
text/scanner.(*Scanner).next(0xc420285b80, 0x0)
    /home/chaos/android_build/prebuilts/go/linux-x86/src/text/scanner/scanner.go:284 +0x3c9
text/scanner.(*Scanner).Peek(0xc420285b80, 0x268)
    /home/chaos/android_build/prebuilts/go/linux-x86/src/text/scanner/scanner.go:316 +0x4a
text/scanner.(*Scanner).Scan(0xc420285b80, 0x0)
    /home/chaos/android_build/prebuilts/go/linux-x86/src/text/scanner/scanner.go:540 +0x2f
github.com/google/blueprint/parser.(*parser).next(0xc420285b80)
    build/blueprint/parser/parser.go:156 +0x4f
github.com/google/blueprint/parser.newParser(0x6c0c80, 0xc420272068, 0xc420214360, 0x68df3d)
    build/blueprint/parser/parser.go:119 +0x172
github.com/google/blueprint/parser.ParseAndEval(0xc420170840, 0x17, 0x6c0c80, 0xc420272068, 0xc420214360, 0x17, 0x0, 0x0, 0x415a28)
    build/blueprint/parser/parser.go:87 +0x43
github.com/google/blueprint.(*Context).parseOne(0xc4200a42c0, 0x68df3d, 0x1, 0xc420170840, 0x17, 0x6c0c80, 0xc420272068, 0xc420214360, 0xc420095a40, 0x50fd08, ...)
    build/blueprint/context.go:938 +0x21d
github.com/google/blueprint.(*Context).openAndParse.func1(0x6c1660, 0xc420272068, 0xc42028ecd8, 0xc420911e58, 0xc4200a42c0, 0x68df3d, 0x1, 0xc420170840, 0x17, 0xc420214360, ...)
    build/blueprint/context.go:902 +0x120
github.com/google/blueprint.(*Context).openAndParse(0xc4200a42c0, 0xc420170840, 0x17, 0xc420214360, 0x68df3d, 0x1, 0xc420095a40, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    build/blueprint/context.go:903 +0x627
github.com/google/blueprint.(*Context).WalkBlueprintsFiles.func1.1(0xc4200a42c0, 0xc420095a40, 0x68df3d, 0x1, 0xc42001ede0, 0xc42001ed80, 0xc42001ee40, 0xc42001eea0, 0xc420094f90, 0xc420018430)
    build/blueprint/context.go:753 +0x84
created by github.com/google/blueprint.(*Context).WalkBlueprintsFiles.func1
    build/blueprint/context.go:752 +0x293
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
17:47:51 soong minibootstrap failed with: exit status 1
```

I'm using

```
Linux version 5.4.0-150-generic (buildd@bos03-amd64-012)
Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04, #167~18.04.1-Ubuntu,
gcc version 7.5.0
openjdk version "9"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9+181-android4627429)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9+181-android4627429, mixed mode
```

I've checked recent changes in `.bp` files but didn't find any obvious syntax errors. I also tried cleaning and rebuilding the project without success.

Has anyone faced a similar issue, or can anyone suggest what might be causing this error and how to resolve it?

Comment: I re-decompressed the compressed file and then compiled it. There was no such error, but a new error was reported.

Comment: the new situation here:
HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
  GEN     ./Makefile
/tmp/cc3HY9IL.o: file not recognized: File truncated